# How can I get user info from a google account?

Tags: android

I want to allow my app users to log on/register with a google account. I need to retrieve the following about a user

A unique id, first name, last name, email

Is it possible in android or do I have to use one of goooles services like picasa api to get this information about a user?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login with Google+

   https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in
2. Retrieve profile info

   https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people